# Focusing on child element, fires blur on parent element

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

Here is my code:

```
<div tabindex="0" id="parent" style="margin-top:200px;margin-left:200px;background-color:black;height:100px;width:200px;">
    <input type="text" style="width:80px;margin:5px auto;display:none">
<div>



$("#parent").blur(function() {
     $(this).css("background-color", "blue").animate({
                marginLeft : '+=50'
            }, 400);
     $("#parent>input").css("display", "none");
   });

   $("#parent>input").focus(function() {
     $(this).css("display", "block");
   });
   $("#parent>input").blur(function() {
     $(this).css("display", "none");
   });
   $("#parent>input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        console.log("enter");
    }
   });
```

Focusing on the input, causes the blur to be fired on parent div and it leads to disappearance of the div, so user is not able to enter any text inside the textbox!

http://jsfiddle.net/z7Erv/10/

any idea?

Comment: What is the full workflow? I know what you want, but your current solution is bad. So need to know all the steps so that I proper implementation can be done.

Comment: I'm trying to mimic google docs/word comment plugin, so when users focus the comment area, I need to move (animate) the comment div to the left (close to main document) and make the textbox visible, then let them to enter some comment and on blur, move the div (comment area) to right and make textbox invisible again!

Comment: the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259754/ie-click-on-child-does-not-focus-parent-parent-has-tabindex-0

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this question is outdated - is this maybe what you want to do?:
https://jsfiddle.net/1280pn4n/1/

```
$('#parent').bind('focusin focusout', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('showup');
});
```

I just had the same issue and the answer from Keltex helped (use focusin/focusout instead of onfocus/blur):

[jQuery figuring out if parent has lost 'focus'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195877/jquery-figuring-out-if-parent-has-lost-focus)

Comment: Your answer helped me out, I had been trying focus/blur on a div and ul for hours. Thanks!