# jquery focus to sibling without focusing out from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-focusout

I am try to iterate through all `li` elements in `ul` on `keydown` event by firing `focus()` event for next sibling `li`. In this process, I dont want to focus out from parent `ul`. 
But its not happening. Even changing focus on siblings is causing focusout event on parent. I want that only when someone clicks somewhere else on the screen should focus out of parent be fired.

```js
var KEY_DOWN=40;

$(document).on('keydown', 'li', function(e){
 let keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
 if(keyCode == KEY_DOWN)
 {
  if($(this).next().length != 0)
  {
   $(this).next().focus();
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).parent().children().first().focus();
  }
  return false;
 }
});

$(document).on('focusout','ul', function(e)
{
 console.log('focused')
});
```

```css
li
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li:focus
{
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul tabindex="-1">
<li tabindex="-1">First</li>
<li tabindex="-1">Second</li>
<li tabindex="-1">Third</li>
</ul>
```

In the snippet, focused in getting printed on every down key press. How to solve this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiple HTML elements receive focus at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017011/can-multiple-html-elements-receive-focus-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @A.Lau dunno. why people mark duplicate without reading properly. definitely not a duplicate. I am not asking definition. If focus event does not work here, it requires some other event suggestion here which solves the problem.

Comment: May I know why you want to detect focus out of ul. Why not just use click event on anywhere except the ul

Comment: @KiranDash Is that the only solution? It can be done but I thought if focusout, focus, focusin, blur are there then they can be used somehow. I mean like asking the element to react rather than asking everyone else to react for that element.

Comment: `I am try to iterate through all li elements in ul on keydown event by firing focus()` well my 'duplicate' pretty much outlines you can't. You can only focus on at a time.

Comment: You mean no solution for this problem is there? It can't be done? I am here just telling what I am using, not necessarily I am compelled to use that.

Comment: Your question does not ask that, you are asking why focus doesn't work.

Comment: Nops... I am in last line asking how to solve this situation.

Comment: Only duplicate is suggesting that its unsolvable which I suppose is not. Unless it solves the original problem, you should not mark it duplicate.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar You can use the event data to check the current focused out element. But just to get a perfect solution I believe the `click` solution will suit best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I found was to disable focusout event on parent ul when I am trying to focus any li

```js
var KEY_DOWN=40;

$(document).on('keydown', 'li', function(e){
 let keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
 if(keyCode == KEY_DOWN)
 {
                $(document).off('blur','ul', doWork);
  if($(this).next().length != 0)
  {
   $(this).next().focus();
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).parent().children().first().focus();
  }
                $(document).on('blur','ul', doWork);
  return false;
 }
});

doWork = function(e)
{
 console.log('focused')
};

$(document).on('blur','ul', doWork);
```

```css
li
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li:focus
{
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul tabindex="-1">
<li tabindex="-1">First</li>
<li tabindex="-1">Second</li>
<li tabindex="-1">Third</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to event bubbling, the focusout event is logging the message for you when you are focusing out of `li` too. You can use the `event` data to check from where you have focused out. (Read more here: [jQuery figuring out if parent has lost 'focus'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195877/jquery-figuring-out-if-parent-has-lost-focus))

But I would like to mention how I do it. I would rather like to detect click outside my `ul`.

```js
var KEY_DOWN=40;

$(document).on('keydown', 'li', function(e){
 let keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
 if(keyCode == KEY_DOWN)
 {
  if($(this).next().length != 0)
  {
   $(this).next().focus();
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).parent().children().first().focus();
  }
  return false;
 }
});

$(document).on('focusout','ul', function(e)
{
    console.log('focused out of li');
});

$(document).click(function() {
    console.log('focused out of ul');
});

$('ul').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
li
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li:focus
{
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul tabindex="-1">
<li tabindex="-1">First</li>
<li tabindex="-1">Second</li>
<li tabindex="-1">Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working in snippets. will check it.

Comment: I could not thought it earlier. The problem with this approach is that I want to  do some actions such as removal of some elemets when focusing out of ul. Now if you give this responsibility to clicking outside of element then how will I know that this click is first click outside of ul. I mean clicking outside will happen very frequently, that doesn't mean always focusing out of ul.